Как устранить ошибку Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required?
Загрузил на сервер магазин на ocStore , но выдает такую ошибку:
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/sldybopt/public_html/index.php' 
(include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Как решить данную проблему??

Либо надо создать нужную директорию, или файл......... или дать на него права
